# Can spread operator be used with map function to feed list of fields from a variable

Tags: javascript

The following line works to form the new object from the original report object.
Report object has the fields name, id, result plus bunch of other fields that I don't want in the new object.

```
let newReport = report.map( ({ name, id, result }) => ({ name, id, result }) );
```

However, I do not want to hard code the field names. Would like to get them from a variable.

I have a list of fields in the string array.

```
let fields = ['name', 'id', 'result']
```

I'd like to pass this string array to the map function to avoid hardcoding field names. The following line of code does not perform what I wanted. What would be an elegant way to grab just the fields I like? Thanks.

```
let newReport = report.map(({ ...fields }) => ({ ...fields }));
```